# Loop over id with a function row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i have the following panel data (is much bigger than the example)

```
            id     clae6  anio  trimestre      salario  empleo     cpa letra  
             1  475230.0  2007          1  1372.440000     3.0  3150.0     G   
             1  475230.0  2007          2  1511.554445     3.0  3150.0     G   
             1  475230.0  2007          3  1477.590000     3.0  3150.0     G   
             1  475230.0  2007          4  2058.210000     3.0  3150.0     G   
             1  475230.0  2008          1  1467.678889     2.0  3150.0     G  
             2  475230.0  2007          1  1372.440000     3.0  3150.0     G   
             2  475230.0  2007          2  1511.554445     3.0  3150.0     G   
             2  475230.0  2007          3  1477.590000     3.0  3150.0     G   
             2  475230.0  2007          4  2058.210000     3.0  3150.0     G   
             2  475230.0  2008          1  1467.678889     2.0  3150.0     G
```

I want to perform a certain function by id: my option until now is to use groupby and an apply

```
def entr(x):
if ((x['posicion'] ==1) & (x['fecha'] >= 228)):
    return 1
elif ((x['fecha_dif'] > 8) & (x['fecha'] >= 228)):
    return 1
else:
    return 0

df['entrada'] = df.groupby(['id']).apply(entr,axis=1)
```

Which is inside the function is not relevant to this case, the point is that I think is much faster to loop over each id or each row and made the function that I create but i dont know how, if anyone can help i will be very thankfull.

I think that the group by and apply is very slow (i have a database of 22millions records)

Thank you very much! And sorry for my english (is not my native language, i'am practicing :) )

Comment: look at np.where

Comment: You must explain what are  `posicion`, `fecha`,`fecha_dif `  and why you iterate on groups ....

Comment: Also, look at `np.select` to handle more conditions and results.

Comment: thank you, the np.where works. May i use a group by and then a numpy where?